# Трехвост/трихвост

Tags: орфография, выбор-варианта, сложные-слова

Мы знаем, что используется как часть *три-*, так и часть *тре-* в сложных словах. Какую часть, однако, надо использовать при собственном создании таких слов? Как правильно?

1. Трицветочная глумба, трихвост, трисвет.
2. Трецветочная глумба, трехвост, тресвет.

Ссылки: https://spbdnevnik.ru/news/2017-02-03/kak-pisat-pravilno-slozhnyey-slova-bez-soeydinitelnoy-glasnoy, http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=37#pp37.

Comment: треххвост, у второго слова неясная семантика. Три-тре-цветочная тоже не понятно, о чём речь и Глубма? Глумба Патрис Лумумба?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Спасибо за очередной нестандартный вопрос. Голову изломала — всю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правильно:**

(1) ***Трехцветочная*** клумба — три цветка, не больше. Икебана в парковом искусстве. Выбираем форму ТРЕХ с **прямым** указанием на число.

Остальные формы имеют **отвлеченное или обобщенное** значение (контроль по словарю). И здесь в данном случае свободной творчество, с учетом фонетики и  благозвучия.

(2) ***Трихвост/трехвост***, сравнить **[прохвост](https://dzen.ru/a/W_2hFt_ImwCqhf4w).**

(3) ***Трицветник*** (светофор).

Теория

**ЧИСЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ «ТРИ»**

Сложные слова с числительным «три» образуются с помощью основной количественной формы Р.п. ***ТРЁХ*** и дополнительных форм с обобщённым значением ***ТРЕ*** и ***ТРИ*** (эти исключительные формы рекомендуется запомнить).

Основная форма ***ТРЕХ*** соответствует **ПРЯМОМУ** значению числительного, а остальные формы имеют **обобщенное значение.**

***Трёхместный, трёхпалубный, трёхтомный*** – основная форма ***ТРЁХ***,

***треугольник, трезубец, трезвучие, тренога*** – исключительная форма ***ТРЕ***,

***трилогия, тридесятый, тридевятый, трилистник*** – исключительная форма ***ТРИ***.

**ПРИМЕРЫ**

Петр Первый» – комфортабельный **трехпалубный** теплоход.

**Трезубец** — оружие морского бога Посейдона.

**Трезвучие** определяет основное звучание аккорда.

**Тренога** используется для фиксации опорной стойки.

Роман «Финансист» – первая часть монументальной **трилогии.**

**Трилистник** обозначает Ирландию на гербе Королевства Великобритании.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о выборе ТРЕ и ТРИ)**

**[Почему всё-таки «треугольник» пишется через Е?](https://dzen.ru/b/Yr1zUyhvyUkYfALs)**

В книге «В мире слов» Н. М. Шанский приводит **три слова**, образованные с помощью приставки **тре**- (непродуктивной ныне): ***«треволнение», «трезвон» и «треклятый».***

«Треугольника» среди них нет! Потому что в тех словах приставка тре- обозначает **высокую степень**, «очень» (например, устар. «трегрѣшный» — очень греховный).

Конечно, исторически приставка тре- связана с числом «три» (др.-русск. «трие»). Праслав. *trь̂je родственно др.-инд. tráyas, trī «три», лтш. trîs, греч. τρε.ς (*tri̯es).

Н. М. Шанский уточняет, «что не всякое тре- будет такой приставкой. В словах типа ***«трезубец», «треножник»*** тре- представляет собой уже сочетание корня числительного тр- и соединительной гласной е». К этим словам относится и слово «треугольник», известное с начала XVIII века!

Лингвисты объясняют такое написание тем, что здесь подразумевалось **количественное числительное «трёх»**, как в слове «трёхгранник» (ранее было зафиксировано написание «трегранник»). Сюда же можно отнести устаревшее слово «трегубый»(с двойною верхнею губою), «треденный» (т. е. «трёхдневное» ожидание).

Comment: Так когда тре, когда три, когда трёх?

Comment: ТРЕХ – когда надо указать число "три". Если у нас не только прямое, но дополнительное (качественное) значение, то ТРЕ и ТРИ.   Сравним с ДВУХ и ДВУ.  Двусоставное предложение, двудольные растения – здесь определенное качество, а не только число. ТРЕ и ТРИ сложились исторически, и у них тоже есть новое качество. К примеру, трезвучие  – одно из основных понятий в музыке.

Comment: То есть можно писать как, например, *тригаражный*, так и *трегаражный*?

Comment: Можно использовать обе формы, но ТРИ буде скорее обозначать просто число, а форма ТРЕ - высокую степень (трегаражный!)

Answer (score 1):

• [Трёхцветный](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/245182) — имеющий три цвета, окрашенный в три цвета.
Но нам нужны не цвета́, а цветы́.
Тогда — **трёхцветочный** букет (их трёх цветков); трёхцветочная клумба и трёхцветочное поле (там растут цветы трёх видов).

*Я дарю вам букет.

Не увянут цветки

Ни от гнета руки,

Ни под тяжестью лет.*

*Букв резных лепестки

Не изменят свой цвет.

Лучше вазы им нет,

Чем ритмичность строки.*

*Мыслезвуки легки.

**Трехцветочный** сюжет.

Я дарю вам букет,

Превращенный в стихи.*
Н. Скорнякова

• [**Трёххвостый**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_orthography/90937/%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9) — в орфографических словарях ( Б. З. Букчина, Л. П. Какалуцкая. 1998; С. И. Ожегов, А. Б. Шапиро. 1957 (печатный вариант)).
Трехвостый и трёххвостый (Т. Ф. Ефремова) — прил. 1. Имеющий три хвоста. 2. Имеющий разделенный натрое конец.

Получаем: [трёххвостка](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/255744/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%85%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0) и трехвостка → **трёххвост** (мне больше нравится) и **трехвост**.

Находим примеры в Нацкорпусе (*трехвостый* — нет):

*И действительно, приспособления были любые, вплоть до **трёххвостого** хлыста с вольфрамовыми спиральками...* (Сергей Осипов. Страсти по Фоме. Книга третья. Книга Перемен);
*На тех картинках изображались разные диковинные **трёххвостые** чудища, четвероногие орлы-грифоны и другие сказочные звери и птицы...* (С. М. Голицын. Тайна старого Радуля).

• **Трёхсветовой** (я бы так написала) — имеющий освещение трёх разных типов (или имеющий скорость в три скорости света?) → **трёхсвет**.

*Особенно уникальным в этом проекте оказался сам зал: большой, **трёхсветовой**, с отличной акустикой* (Е. Разинкова. Филармонические концертные залы).

Answer (score 1):

Трёх - когда это какой-то важный, но не исключительный элемент конструкции, - трехпалубный корабль, трехтомный роман. У меня два тома трехтомного романа - роман не теряет смысла, от потери одного из томов, хотя становится неполной конструкцией. Двухмачтовый корабль, сломав одну мачту, доплыл в порт. Относительное количество, совсем не обязательное, в противопоставлении чему-то.

Три - когда речь идет об исключительном, характером отличии, признаке, но опять же конструкции. Трилогия - это не дилогия, а другая логия. Трилогия - это не какой-то уникальный роман, но принцип деления на три различные части. Триера - корабль с характерной особенностью расположения весел по три. Трилистник - отличительная особенность расположения листьев.  Встречающееся, повторяющееся, характерное три. Трёхчастное в составе целого, характерное отличие вида.

Тре - когда одно создано из трех. τριγωνο - треугольник, - порожденный тремя; орган - орган, образованный, образующий, скорее всего родственное, организация - образование, создание. Треух - шапка закрывающая уши и затылок, образованная тремя ушками. Трезубец - копье с тремя концами, образованный или образующий три конца, о трех концах. Тренога - не потому, что три ноги, а потому что на двух ногах не стоит конструкция, нет иных вариантов.

Тре- как приставка может приобретать совершенную степень сходную с весьма, очень - трезвон, треволнения, треклятый. Хотя слов с тре- не так много.

тре- больше тяготеет к трои-, троичный код, Троица.

Теперь по словам:

Треххвост - без вариантов. Вариант "трехвост" - это какое-то название вроде прохвост или треклятый, но в целом не понятно что, поэтому нет. *Трихвост* - может быть, если это название растения, а не животного.

*Трисвет* - тоже не ясно что такое, если "трицвет" - то тоже очень слабое слово, так как есть **трихроизм** - трёхцветный. Цвет - не является обязательным элементом, так что "трёх".

То есть: трех < три < тре~трои.

Без трех палуб корабль все равно корабль, без триатлона - атлет не тот самый, любой многоугольник можно разбить на треугольники - без треугольника многоугольники не мыслимы.

И глумба - это клумба или какая-то чушь.